# Strict Mode in React prompts Open Layer duplication errors

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6

Version: `"ol": "^6.14.1",`

I am trying to add a marker to an OpenLayer map in React, but whenever I click on the map I get the error: `Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/doc/errors/#58 for details.` which comes from the code `map.addLayer(newMarkersLayer);`.

The error states that: `Duplicate item added to a unique collection. For example, it may be that you tried to add the same layer to a map twice. Check for calls to map.addLayer() or other places where the map's layer collection is modified.`

This duplication happens because `React.StricMode` is wrapped around my app. If I disable strict mode, clicking on the map adds a marker.

I don't want to disable strict mode, because I still think that the error comes from my way of implementing the map in React using a badly written `useEffect()`.

How should I add a marker on an OpenLayers map in React so that StrictMode doesn't adds duplicates ?

Map component:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
// import ModalUI from '../UI/ModalUI';
import classes from './MapUI.module.css';
import { drawerActions } from '../Rooms/Drawers/drawerSlice';

import 'ol/ol.css';
import { Map, View, Overlay, Feature } from 'ol';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import { fromLonLat, toLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
import { toStringHDMS } from 'ol/coordinate';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

import PopUp from './PopUp';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export default function MapUI() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const popup = useRef();
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState('');
  const [newMarker, setNewMarker] = useState(
    new Feature({
      geometry: new Point([[]]),
      name: '',
    })
  );

  const [newMarkersLayer] = useState(
    new VectorLayer({
      properties: { name: 'newMarkers' },
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [newMarker],
      }),
    })
  );

  const closePopup = () => {
    map.getOverlayById('map-popup').setPosition(undefined);
    map.removeLayer(newMarkersLayer);
  };

  const [map] = useState(
    new Map({
      target: '',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
        new VectorLayer({
          properties: { name: 'existingMarkers' },
          source: new VectorSource({
            // features: [marker],
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([26.08, 44.46]),
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 20,
      }),
    })
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const overlay = new Overlay({
      element: popup.current,
      id: 'map-popup',
      autoPan: {
        animation: {
          duration: 250,
        },
      },
    });
    // console.log('useEffect in MapUI.jsx');

    map.addOverlay(overlay);
    map.setTarget(mapRef.current);
    map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
      map.addLayer(newMarkersLayer);
      dispatch(drawerActions.closeDrawer());
      newMarker.getGeometry().setCoordinates(evt.coordinate);
      // console.log(typeof evt.coordinate);

      setCoordinates(toStringHDMS(toLonLat(evt.coordinate)));
      overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    });
  }, [newMarkersLayer, map, newMarker, dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        ref={mapRef}
        className='map-container'
      />
      <div id='map-popup' className={classes['ol-popup']} ref={popup}>
        <PopUp coordinates={coordinates} closePopup={closePopup} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: To avoid `map.addLayer(newMarkersLayer);` throwing the error you could call `map.removeLayer(newMarkersLayer);` immediately before it.  But it seems inefficient to add a layer for each click.  You could simply clear the marker `newMarker.getGeometry().setCoordinates([]);` in `closePopup` instead of calling `map.removeLayer(newMarkersLayer);` then adding it again later.

Comment: My end goal is to be able to have two arrays of markers on the map: one would contain pre-defined markers for that map/region/city and one would be used for the ability of the user to add new markers on the map. So the map should have multiple markers. If I remove the marker layers how can the map hold markers ?

Answer (score 1):

React strict mode intentionally double calls certain handlers to force you to make clean and reusable components - which yours is not.

Either accept this fact and remove strict mode which will be only a hinderance for you, or - if you are planning to make reusable components - try to follow its guidelines. As [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118270/mike) pointed out, you probably should not create a new layer on each click.

Also, I would like to point there are React components for OpenLayers (I am the author) at https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers

Comment: I am still learning to make reusable components, especially when integrating vanilla JS tools. I was avoiding using `React components for OpenLayers ` because I am afraid of them not being maintained.
I am trying to add markers to a marker layer with each click. The way I did it was one way of adding markers that I found in a tutorial.
In the end my map should have an array of markers that can't be changed by the users, and another array that will be used so the user can add multiple markers.